# Titan : Filter connected vertices

Tags: titan

I am using Titan using JAVA. I have following situation:

There is post vertex,many user write comments on this post same user can post multiple comments on it.

```
U(email, name, sex)
```

What I have to do is, I have to send notification to all commenter if any new comment is posted.

Now the thing is how can i filter users i.e if there is situation like

```
U1 ------COMMENTED ----------> POST
U2 ------COMMENTED ----------> POST
U3 ------COMMENTED ----------> POST
U1 ------COMMENTED ----------> POST
```

If a new comment is posted, notification should be sent to `U1` `U2` `U3`. Now if i iterate through incoming edge `COMMENTED` it fetch `U1` twice. But i need `U1` only once just to get their email. How can I achieve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know your question was about Java, but the Gremlin Groovy sessions below demonstrate the approach.  One way would be to use the `dedup` step.

http://gremlindocs.com/#filter/dedup

That will ensure that `U1` exists only once after that step as shown here:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.V.out.in
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
==>v[1]
==>v[1]
==>v[1]
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
==>v[1]
==>v[4]
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V.out.in.dedup
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
==>v[1]
```

Alternatively you could write all users to a `Set`:

```
gremlin> x = [] as Set
gremlin> g.V.out.in.fill(x);null
==>null
gremlin> x
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
==>v[1]
```

Comment: got it but neither option is available in java side. seems will have to do manually.

Comment: No reason you can't use the `Dedup` in Java but maybe you're not using Gremlin.  `Set` is a standard java collection. Write all the vertices to that and when it is done doing that the `Set` will only contain unique vertices.